# .htaccess / iirf.ini edits to rewrite home page URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using an IIS component called Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter on a website to handle URL rewriting. It is designed to use nearly identical syntax as .htaccess.

I have the following in place:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.htm [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.asp [NC,L]
```

It works, however it does not work for my home page URL: www.mydomain.com

On an Apache host, this isn't a problem... all URLs work fine. But something isn't working right with IIRF. I need to add a rule that will handle if there is nothing after the ".com". That would be as simple as adding a RewriteRule either before or after the two lines I have already?

My knowledge of writing .htaccess syntax is very limited, I would appreciate any help.

My default document is default.htm, so I just need it so that if nothing (or just a slash) appears after the ".com" in my URL, then default.htm will be the document loaded.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this *before* your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ default.htm [L]
```

Comment: That isn't fixing it for me. Of course, there might be something about it that would work for .htaccess but not IIRF. I just get a "page not found" error.